# Java Swing GUI control ceases while and operation is performed in the backend

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[image]

Now when I click on the import button an operation is performed in the backend. For that while the GUI ceases control and I can't press any button but I want the cancel button to be available for pressing so that the user can cancel the ongoing operation. 
I need some ideas on how to do it.

```
JButton importButton = new JButton("Import");
importButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


    for(ResourceListObject currentImage : imagesToBeImported){

        String ImOid = String.valueOf(currentImage.getOID());


            String image_content = restEngine.getimageContent(ImOid);

            String str[]=new String[3];

            str[0] = "aix";
            str[1] = image_content;
            str[2] = selectedRepository.concat("_").concat(currentImage.getName());

            PowerVC_Image_Deployer imgDeployer= new PowerVC_Image_Deployer(str);



             }

        }
```

Comment: i think we can help, if you can post your code, or generated exception.

Comment: @Papa_Jay : No exception is generated. I just can't click the cancel button. I am posting the import button code.

Comment: I have added the code for "Import" Button. The PowerVC_Image_Deployer is a class that makes a connection to the server and performs the operation. I am unable to press the Cancel button that time while the Power_VC_Image_Deployer performs its operations int the backend.

Comment: Contrary to Papa_Jay's comment, this is not due to an exception or an error, but typical behavior of a single threaded program. Please look into the link I posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that the GUI is calling the operation and blocks i.e. it waits for that operation to finish and since it's waiting, there can be no user interaction. To solve that problem you have to use multiple threads in your application.

> Careful use of concurrency is particularly important to the Swing
>   programmer. A well-written Swing program uses concurrency to create a
>   user interface that never "freezes" — the program is always responsive
>   to user interaction, no matter what it's doing. To create a responsive
>   program, the programmer must learn how the Swing framework employs
>   threads.

You can find more information here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: Ok ,if I am getting it correctly that means I have to make the GUI as a thread, and the class that performs the operation in the backend as a separate thread ??

Comment: Quoting from the link : `The programmer does not need to provide code that explicitly creates these threads: they are provided by the runtime or the Swing framework. The programmer's job is to utilize these threads to create a responsive, maintainable Swing program.` Please read through that short tutorial before you refactor your code and possibly introduce erros, it'll make things clearer for you.